# DropDownListForModel Can't add HTML attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to add html attributes to this drop down list like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListForModel(p => p.PreviousCompanyCompletedMappingId, Model.PreviousCompanyMappings.ToSelectListItems(), new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

But I am getting error: `Argument 4: cannot convert from '<anonymous type: string class>' to 'string'`

Comment: Could you show code for DropDownListForModel method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler has a problem identifying the correct method overload to use. Explicitly specify `null` for the `optionLabel` parameter.

```
@Html.DropDownListForModel(p => p.PreviousCompanyCompletedMappingId, Model.PreviousCompanyMappings.ToSelectListItems(), null, new { @class = "dropdown" })
```